# How can you split import text to different variables

Tags: matlab

I have text which is (could be 100K lines like this)

```
time,10 a b,20 c d
```

(time = HH:mm:ss.ffff with milliseconds)

I want to import it into 2 arrays

```
time,a,b
time,c,d
```

whats the shortest way? I need to store the script/code for future use too...

Comment: Your question is not understandable to me! can you show some code sample? or show us what has happened to 10 and 20?

Comment: 10 and 20 are constants. i just know they are there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MATLAB has several text input options. While regexp-based options (like textscan) are often effective, it sounds like you have a fixed format that might be better handled by manually reading the lines sequentially. I've found that performance with this method is more consistent than with textscan or import. If a, b, c, d are not fixed width, you'll need to do something else. In that case, I'd just use the import wizard to set up the input, and then save the import code and modify as needed to automate it.

```
array1 = NaN(<numberoflines>,6);
array2 = NaN(<numberoflines>,6);
fname = 'path_to_some_file';
fid = fopen(fname);
stop = 0;
jj = 1;
while ~stop
    cline = fgetl(fid);
    if ischar(cline)
        HH = str2double(cline(1:2));
        MM = str2double(cline(...));
        ...
        array1(jj,:) = [HH MM SS MS a b];
        array2(jj,:) = ...;
    else
        disp('End of file')
        stop = 1;
    end
end
fclose(fid)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`regexp`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html). A very powerful tool for parsing strings in matlab.

Comment: I really hate regex in principle. can it be done in a plane script or something?